# HSTS missing by Nessus even JBoss EAP 7 is configured

Tags: jboss7.x, nessus

JBoss EAP 7.3

We configured as below and we could see HSTS header was displayed in the Chrome dev tools

```
<filters>
    <response-header name="hsts-header" header-name="Strict-Transport-Security" header-value="max-age=31536000;"/>
</filters>
```

But Nessus still detects the vulnerability HSTS missing (RFC 6797)

Is this is a bug of Nessus ?
Because we tried Fortify WebInspect to scan and HSTS check passed.
Or any configuration to modify standalone.xml for this ?

BTW, we disabled admin console (customer requirment) so there's nothing inside

Many thakns.

We found Red Hat document
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7018417
but this seems workable for admin console ONLY.